# What MySQL storage engine should I choose?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have a database for my catalog webpage. Some tables are about 3GB with millions of rows.

What engine should I choose for my database, InnoDB or MyISAM?

There will only be about 1,000 new records a week, and about 1,000 deletes, but I will modify some data in one table quite often (price, quantity, etc.).  All other tables will be "sealed".

I need indexes to enable fast queries. Which storage engine is best for this scenario?

Answer (score 5):

My recommendations are to start as follows:

1. Go for the latest version of the MySQL Server that you can get, there have been some pretty impressive work done on 5.6 although the production ready version is 5.5
2. Go for InnoDB - comes as the default for the higher MySQL versions
3. Configure InnoDB as follows:

   - file_per_table - creates an data file for each table instead of putting all tables in a single data files
   - innodb_buffer_pool_size - 80% of available RAM (if a dedicated machine) so that as much of your database is in memory
4. Table column characteristics:

   - use the smallest column size needed for the data
   - use numeric foreign keys
   - index the columns used in the searches, and setup the indexes to cover the most common searches, for example if you search on columns 4, then 6 alot create a multi-column index with column 4 first followed by 6

Remember these are just starting points you can fine tune specifics as you move along, but before you fine tune, measure tune then measure again

Comment: a `varchar(50)` column  with two characters does not take more space than a `varchar(500)` with two characters. So I don't understand the "use the smalles column size needed" comment.

Comment: For a fixed number of characters say US state use CHAR(2), if you have a column with a range of numbers, using an unsigned TINYINT for 0 - 255 is better than BIGINT or plain INT, if you only need a date use DATE instead of DATETIME, VARCHAR(255) is smaller than VARCHAR(256) and above which are taken as blobs (If I remember correctly)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have removed the statement specifying its for varchar columns only, thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: There are limitations on indices though, that depend on the size of the char columns.

Comment: @ypercube: does that mean you cannot create indices on "large" varchar/char columns? (Not that they usually make sense though for really large values)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I don't remember all the details but I'm sure you can't have a Unique index on more than 767 bytes in InnoDB (so, only up to `VARCHAR(255)` if you use utf8). If it's a multi-column index, the limit is larger.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: also...when the optimizer tries to see if it can do a sort in memory or needs to write the rows at disk, it decides that, in part, based on the 'advertised' size of the varchar. So if your column is defined as 1000 characters but on average has 30, you are setting the database up for too many on disk operations than probably needed. You also don't wanna go too low and have to extend later so it is a tough line to walk. But definitely try to avoid being too generous :)

Comment: @TechieGurl: does this mean MySQL doesn't keep track of the average size of a column (or its value distribution)?

Comment: also if i do one time select * from ***, so that my table go to cache, will this help with innodb? Also will this cache be good, after i reboot server?

Comment: @ssmusoke so what do you think?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I am not sure whether the InnoDB cache is persisted after a server restart, however this may help for the latest 5.6 version of MySQL which is going GA in a few weeks http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-performance.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-performance.html for 5.5

Answer (score -1):

pretty sure that's a no since that would be a pretty expensive op if you have a ton of rows and the optimizer is trying to make things fast..so the fastest info it has would come from the table definition. That might have changed post 5.1 FYI